# Resources management mechanism (CPU/Memory) in .NET Aspire

Tags: .net, .net-8.0, dotnet-aspire

Is it possible to limit resources for components in .NET Aspire?

I'm referencing resource management ideas from K8s here. Just wondering if .NET Aspire allows CPU, Memory limitation or there are plans to do that. This is just a random example from K8s docs of something I'm looking for in .NET Aspire:

```
image: images.my-company.example/app:v4
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "64Mi"
    cpu: "250m"
  limits:
    memory: "128Mi"
    cpu: "500m"
```

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to express using the aspire APIs at the moment. Do you want this for development?

Comment: In my current K8s setup this is a substantial part of the configuration. Here is my scenario: I host multiple clients in the same cluster and limit resources.